# How to configure Kibana with Elastic Search and Statsd

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, graphite, statsd

I am trying to do some metric calculation and store the value of the metric in ElasticSearch and view them via Kibana

I followed this tutorial 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-statsd-to-collect-arbitrary-stats-for-graphite-on-ubuntu-14-04

and it helped me to set up StatsD with graphite UI, Carbon and Whiper as Back-end.

Now I want to use StatsD with ElasticSearch and Kibana as Visualization tool.

The issue I am facing is that Kibana has its own aggregation technique and I have already done so using statsd, eg: uniq counts.
So I just want to plot the data which I store in Elastic Search and not aggregate it further, 
Is this possible to view data without aggregating them in Kibana.?

Kindly Help.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Nor have you told us any errors you got when trying to set this up, or what step doesn't work or really anything useful to go on.

Comment: Thanks Rumbles for pointing it out. I have updated the question with specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via statsd(client) + metricbeat(statsd plugin that runs daemon) and Elasticsearch + Kibana. Following steps:

set up elasticsearch : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rpm.html

```
rpm --import https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
```

vi /etc/yum.repos.d/elasticsearch.repo and input:

```
[elasticsearch]
name=Elasticsearch repository for 7.x packages
baseurl=https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/yum
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
enabled=0
autorefresh=1
type=rpm-md
```

and install elasticsearch from above configured repo:

```
sudo yum install --enablerepo=elasticsearch elasticsearch
```

set up (systemctl) service:

```
sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload
sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
```

which can be started/stopped as follows:

```
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service
sudo systemctl stop elasticsearch.service
```

similarly, set up kibana, by just following : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/rpm.html

vi /etc/yum.repos.d/kibana.repo

```
[kibana-7.x]
name=Kibana repository for 7.x packages
baseurl=https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/yum
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
enabled=1
autorefresh=1
type=rpm-md
```

and install kibana : `sudo yum install kibana`
You can similarly enable, start/stop systemd services for kibana also.

I have the elasticsearch and kibana co-located, on same single node set up.

Now, just use a statsd client, in a flask application for example:

```
from flask import Flask
from elasticapm.contrib.flask import ElasticAPM
from statsd import StatsClient
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime
import time

statsd = StatsClient(host='0.0.0.0',port=8125,prefix='test')
app = Flask(__name__)
apm = ElasticAPM(app)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    bfr = time.time()
    time.sleep(3)
    statsd.incr('baz',2)
    statsd.decr('ban')
    statsd.gauge('foo',-3,delta=True)
    statsd.set('users',randint(0,100))
    statsd.timing('req',int((time.time() - bfr)*1000))
    return "Hello World!"
```

This sets up our statsd client, for statsd server, just go to : `http://<es-ip>:5601/app/kibana#/home/tutorial/statsdMetrics` and follow up instructions.

Set the metricbeat, enable statsd on the same server as flask application. steps are:

curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/metricbeat/metricbeat-7.8.1-x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -vi metricbeat-7.8.1-x86_64.rpm

modify `output.elasticsearch` section in `/etc/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml`:

```
sudo metricbeat modules enable statsd
```

and setup things i.e metricbeat / statsd:

```
sudo metricbeat setup
sudo service metricbeat start
```

You can do a `netstat -tulpn | grep -i 8125` and see a statsd daemon running.

Next, just go to "dev tools" kibana section

and fire following query to check the statsd metrics : `http://<es-ip>:5601/app/kibana#/dev_tools/console`

```
GET /_search
{"query":{"bool":{"filter":{"term":{"event.module":"statsd"}}}},"size":10}
```

You can now go, create a dashboard, add visualizations with query filters 'event.module' is 'statsd', and even search for terms like .... e.g  `accounts.authentication.login.num_users`